# Issue with code working on WinXP but not Win7. Why?

Tags: c#, windows-7, datagridview, windows-xp, bindingsource

I've been having an issue with my code recently that I can't seem to figure out. I was using a computer that was running WinXP when I first wrote the code. But now I'm trying to run the exact same code on a computer running Win7 and it won't work. Now when I say it won't work, I mean specific lines of code won't work. The rest of the code runs.

Here is the code in question:

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    GetData("SELECT Lastname, Firstname, DOB, SSAN, Minor FROM Children WHERE Children.ParentID = " + id + "");
```

The above code is in my Form1_Load, and is supposed to run and fill the dataGridView when the program opens.

Here is the GetData() method:

```
    private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = U:/Syndicate II/Syndicate II.accdb;Persist Security Info = False"; //"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:/Documents and Settings/David/Desktop/SyndicateII/SyndicateII/Syndicate II.accdb;Persist Security Info = False";

            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        }
        catch(OleDbException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("didn't work");
        }
    }
```

These two chunks of code are whats giving me problems. Like I said, it works on the WinXP computer. But when i run it on the Win7 computer, it doesn't work. I've tried testing it by placing message boxes in the code to see if they run and they don't. So it seems that the chunks of code are just not running, and I don't know why. And to make things a little more confusing, the code used to work. When I first started using the Win7 comp, the code worked. After a while it would work sometimes. And now it just doesn't work.

I hope I have given a clear description of my issue. And any help I could get would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running 64bit Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, I am running 64bit.

Comment: as an aside you may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, if you haven't mitigated that you should probably look into it.

Comment: Doesn't work is a bit vague. Could you tell us what error you receive? On which line your code fails?

Comment: I don't receive an error. The dataGridView just doesn't populate with data(no columns, rows, or anything). Its just a gray square. I added a MessageBox.Show("hi") after the first chunk of code I posted. And when I ran the program, the message never showed. So it has to be completely skipping the code for some reason I'm guessing.

Comment: I'd guess it's a file permission issue. Ensure that the U: drive has the appropriate permissions set

Comment: The U drive is not what I'm using on the Win7 comp. Thats from the WinXP comp which I'm using now since the code works on it. On the Win7 comp, the database is located on my desktop. So the connection string goes something like this: C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Syndicate II.accdb

Comment: But you still may be right. But like I said though, it used to work. Not sure how the permissions would just change like that.

Comment: Just checked, permissions are good.

Comment: I'd start debugging, place a breakpoint at the line" GetData("SELECT..." and if it breaks there then F10 through and see where it diverges, if it doesn't break there then place a breakpoint earlier in your code and see where it is failing.